# The console reads: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined.

Tags: jquery

I have code similar to what is listed below in other areas of my projects, but for some reason this isn't working. When I remove top the console reads top isn't defined in the jquery file which doesn't make sense either.  Can someone help me and not rate my question as inappropiate.  This should be a place to recieve help not be judge by know it alls.

```
var $w = $(window).scroll(function(){
    var targetOffset = $("#team").offset().top -220;
    if ( $w.scrollTop() > targetOffset ) {
        $.each($('.team-content article'), function(i, el){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(el).addClass('animated zoomIn')
                $(el).css({
                    'visibility': 'visible',
                    '-webkit-animation-duration': '.8s'
                });
            }, ( i * 300 ));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Being in your website's page, open the javascript console. What does `$("#team").offset();` display?

Comment: It displays four divs containing team members

Comment: All 4 divs are child elements of `<div id="team">` ?

Comment: Did you wrap it to .ready method?

Comment: Yes these are child elements and all functions are wrapped in .ready method.

Comment: What do you mean by "When I remove top", I'm just trying to understand your scenario to see if I can be of any help

Comment: Post your whole code so that we can get the whole perspective of the code.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help I decided to go a different route to solve my problem